# select a radgrid row from outside radgid event?

Tags: checkbox, telerik, radgrid

Is there a way to select a radgrid row from outside radgrid event for example like from inside a buttonclick event? I have a ragrid with a column "productname", some other columns and a GridClientSelectColumn(checkbox).

My page also has a textbox and a button. When user type a product name, say 'n', in textbox and press button, I want the checkbox of row containing that particular product name to get checked.

Is this possible? The reason why I want this in because, my users will scan the product name using barcode scanner.

Comment: This is very simple... When your text box is submitted, just loop through the grid and find the corresponding ID value and then check that box.  
What might be better though, if they are scanning a barcode is just to have them select the product from a dropdown menu or enter the ID and then just show the barcode.  That could eliminate some user error.

Comment: Can you provide me with code to loop through grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with code snippet.

.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
        // By using Datakey
        if (item.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString() == "1")
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }

        // By using column
        if (item["Name"].Text== "Name1") // "Name" is column unique name
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

.aspx

```
<MasterTableView  DataKeyNames="ID">

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```